# 2D Augmented Reality in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 2d, detection, augmented-reality

I want to setup an AS3 Flash project whereby I can use AR technology to detect via webcam the X, Y coordinates and distance of a printed symbol at any given time.

I want to use this data eventually, to place MovieClips and/or video on the screen that can be interacted with. For an example.. If the symbol is in the top left corner of the screen, load MovieClip A onto the screen. If Symbol is in bottom right corner, load MovieClip B and attach it to the symbol on the screen, etc.

I've looked at FLAR already, but it's documentation is in Japanese, and tutorials are sparse. Furthermore, it seems that most AR solutions/libraries are designed for transformation and rotation of 3D objects. This is far beyond the simplicity of what I want to achieve. Documentation is not very informative either, for someone who has never worked with AR before.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suppose you mean "Augmented Reality" instead of "Alternate Reality"

Comment: Besides FLAR, there is also IN2AR (http://www.in2ar.com/)

Comment: Search for tutorials and example code -- there is a lot of it -- or try translating website (at present, Google [seems to do a pretty good job](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.libspark.org%2F&act=url)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.libspark.org/wiki/saqoosha/FLARToolKit/en
helper classes for major flash 3D engines (Papervision3D, Away3D, Sandy, Alternativa3D) are included.